# Convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.expression.Expression' for property 'onFailureExpression'

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am facing below error and using spring version 5.3.14 and Spring_integration 5.5.7 and using camel version 2.25.4.

```
  org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.expression.Expression' for property 'onFailureExpression'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.expression.Expression' for property 'onFailureExpression': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

config file:

```
<int:filter id="xpathfilter" input-channel="eventSpringXpathChannel"
        output-channel="eventSpringOutChannel" discard-channel="eventSpringFailureChannel"
        expression="#xpath(payload, headers.get('xpathKey'), 'boolean')">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
<bean           class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
    <property name="onFailureExpression" value="payload" />
    <property name="failureChannel" ref="eventSpringXpathErrorChannel" />
    <property name="trapException" value="true" />
</bean>
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:filter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That setter expects an instance of `org.springframework.expression.Expression`, but you provide just `value="payload"`, which is indeed not an `Expression`.

See another setter:

```
/**
 * Set the expression to evaluate against the root message after a failed
 * handler invocation. The exception is available as the variable {@code #exception}.
 * Defaults to {@code payload}, if {@code failureChannel} is configured.
 * @param onFailureExpression the SpEL expression.
 * @since 4.3.7
 */
public void setOnFailureExpressionString(String onFailureExpression) {
```

So, you config will look like:

```
<property name="onFailureExpressionString" value="payload" />
```

Comment: Also `payload` is the default expression when a `failureChannel` is provided.

Comment: this is the followine error getting now

Comment: org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException:
 Failed to transform Message in bean 'org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformingHandler#1';
 defined in: 'class path resource [META-INF/spring/integration/core-context.xml]'; from source: ''int:header-enricher''; 
 nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred during processing message in 'MethodInvokingMessageProcessor'

Comment: [org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor@8ce5558]; 
 nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader cannot be cast to class java.net.URLClassLoader 
 (jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader and java.net.URLClassLoader are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'),

Comment: Sorry, those errors are not related to the question. Consider to start new SO thread. See rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask